# How can i iterate through all items in the Session in laravel?

Tags: session, loops, laravel

as i said in the Title, i'm looking for a way in **Laravel** to **iterate** through all items in **session**. is there any way to do this ?!

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply as this

```
foreach(Session::all() as $key => $obj):
    echo $key . ": ";
    print_r($obj);
    echo "\n----------\n";
endforeach;
```